# How could I remove the corrupted file from SVN?

Tags: svn

When I recover my SVN repo from a dump, I found there are some error in one of the branch. The author column is showing  `###error###` in TortoiseSVN. When I'm trying to open the file, the message prompt on me `Unable to connect to a repository at URL <THE_URL> Corrupt representation 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

When I check on the SVN log file, it shows me this:

```
[Fri Feb 28 14:07:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] (160004)APR does not understand this error code: Can't fetch proplist of '<file_path>': Corrupt node-revision 'ju-1679.0.r1679/47785'
[Fri Feb 28 14:07:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] (160004)APR does not understand this error code: Can't get created-rev of '<file_path>': Corrupt node-revision 'j5-1679.0.r1679/47431'
[Fri Feb 28 14:07:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] (160004)APR does not understand this error code: Can't get created-rev of '<file_path>': Corrupt node-revision 'j5-1679.0.r1679/47431'
[Fri Feb 28 14:07:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] (160004)APR does not understand this error code: Can't fetch proplist of '<file_path>': Corrupt node-revision 'j5-1679.0.r1679/47431'
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:04 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:04 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Error checking kind of path '/branches/2.0/externalJar' in repository  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:04 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Corrupt node-revision 'bp-1557.0.r1557/87025'  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:04 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Found malformed header 'ream' in revision file  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:07 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:07 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Error checking kind of path '/branches/1.1/WebContent' in repository  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:07 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Corrupt node-revision '1-1386.0-1393.r1459/4509'  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:07 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Found malformed header '93.r1459/3852' in revision file  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Error checking kind of path '/branches/1.0/.metadata' in repository  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Corrupt node-revision '1-1386.0.r1428/3137'  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Found malformed header '28/2511' in revision file  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:13 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:13 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Error checking kind of path '/branches/1.0/WebContent' in repository  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:13 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Corrupt node-revision '1-1386.0.r1428/3137'  [500, #160004]
[Fri Feb 28 14:08:13 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Found malformed header '28/2511' in revision file  [500, #160004]
```

Since the file is unrecoverable, how could I just remove the particular file to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

You can run [svnadmin verify](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html) on the repository for further analysis of the problem.

If you still wish to completely remove the file from the repositories history use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter)